# Problemas con instalación de paquetes en Rstudio: "Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1"

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, macos, packages

Ayer me cambié de SO, pasé de usar Rstudio en MacOS a Windows, y comúmente mi espacio de trabajo lo hacía directamente desde la nube de OneDrive, en la cual tengo todos mis archivos y scripts. Ahora que me mudé a Windows intenté volver a mi trabajo habitual, comenzando a descargar nuevamente los paquetes que comúmente uso, para dar una idea, estos son los paquetes que iba a instalar:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(plm)
  library(pracma)
  library(lmtest)
  library(sandwich)
  library(haven)
  library(readxl)
  library(stargazer)
  library(margins)
  library(DMwR2)
  library(openxlsx)
```

a los cual, cuando hice un script con la concatenación de la instalación `install.packages(c("...","..."...))` este me arrojó el siguiente error (doy de ejemplo solo mostrando el código de instalación de *tidyverse*, pero fue el mismo que me arrojo cuando intente hacer la instalación en conjunto):

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Matias Vicuña/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/tidyverse_1.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 429006 bytes (418 KB)
downloaded 418 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Matias Vicuña\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp25wFX7\downloaded_packages
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/Matias Vicuña/Documents": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
```

y siendo más especifico, el error que siempre me sale intentando hacer cualquier operación es `Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1`.

Estuve leyendo en algunos foros, y encontré uno que pensé que se me haría útil [Andres'Blog](https://andresrcs.rbind.io/2020/10/26/customizing_library_path/), pero el problema es que las indicaciones que da como cambiar el `.Renviron` o el `.Rprofile.site` no aparecen en mi directorio ubicado en la carpeta de R.

Ya he intentado varias opciones además, como desvicunlar mi dropbox [Foro]([https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unlink-and-re-link-onedrive-3c4680bf-cc36-4204-9ca5-e7b24cdd23ea#:~:text=Open%20OneDrive%20settings%20(select%20the,Select%20Unlink%20this%20PC.)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unlink-and-re-link-onedrive-3c4680bf-cc36-4204-9ca5-e7b24cdd23ea#:%7E:text=Open%20OneDrive%20settings%20(select%20the,Select%20Unlink%20this%20PC.)) o viendo directamente en los ajustes globales de R.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, Saludos!

Comment: Recuerdo que en windows había un tema con las carpetas que usan caracteres no ascii estándar, en tu caso tu usuario tiene al menos una ñ y tal vez un acento,me parece que el problema viene por ahi.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias amigo! era un problema con el nombre de la ruta, tuve que hacer un nuevo usuario y lo correji